# Pre-Load Web Application Pages After Deployment to Prevent Slow Loading

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

We build and deploy our web application to our dev environment automatically every night (using VSTS). When we come into the office in the morning, the first person to access the application has to wait an extended period for each page to load the first time. Subsequent loads are very fast.

The problem has a greater impact in our live environment where, after a deployment, it is potentially an end-user who is the first person to access the application and complain of slowness. To mitigate for this, a member of the team is currently accessing every page of the application manually after deployment to the live environment so that they 'pre-load' every page, which works, but is obviously time-consuming!

I've done a fair bit of searching on the subject, and have configured the appropriate Application Pool in our IIS server (IIS 8.5) so that its `Start Mode` is set to "AlwaysRunning". I've also edited our applicationHost file and set the appropriate Sites with the `preloadEnabled="true"` attribute. I did this after reading the instructions in this very helpful [Microsoft documentation](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization).

However, if I'm reading that documentation correctly, any pre-loading of the website which might alleviate the issue we're having (and I'm not even certain that this is the kind of pre-loading that I'm thinking of) only takes place when the server, the IIS service of the Application Pool are restarted. This isn't happening in our case. We need the pre-loading to take place following a deployment of the application to the IIS server.

Is there a way to automate this pre-loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to perform a HTTP request automatically:

- As soon as the app was deployed (by running a task from the deploying machine)
- Before the application pool has the chance to shut itself down (using Task Scheduler for instance)

Personally, I use a tool that is run in both cases to keep the site warmed up.

#### Advantages

- Robust control over how and when this warm-up is executed.
- It's completely independent from any IIS or web.config setup.

#### Disadvantages

- Generates "bogus" log information.
- Keeps the app permanently in memory (the Pool would never time-out, essentially wasting server resources for sites with a low # of visitors).

#### Sample

Such a tool could be a simple console app written as follows:

```
var taskInfo = new {
    Url = "http://www.a-website-to-keep-warm.url",
    UseHostHeader = true,
    HostHeader = "www.a-website-to-keep-warm.url",
    HttpMethod = "head"
};

HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unused;
long contentLength = 0;

try
{
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(taskInfo.Url);

    webRequest.Method = taskInfo.HttpMethod.ToUpper();
    if(taskInfo.UseHostHeader)
        webRequest.Host = taskInfo.HostHeader;

    using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        //did we warm-up the site successfully?
        statusCode = webResponse.StatusCode;
        contentLength = webResponse.ContentLength;

        //optionally read response headers
        foreach (string header in webResponse.Headers)
        {
            headers.Add(header, webResponse.Headers[header]);
        }
    }

    decimal kilobytes = Math.Round(contentLength / 1024M, 1);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Got {kilobytes:F1} kB with statuscode: \"{statusCode} \" ...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"taskInfo failed with exception: {ex.Message}");
}
```

In my case, I read a bunch of taskInfo objects from a json file and execute them asynchronously every X minutes, making sure X is lower than the Pool-timeout value. It is also run immediately after every deploy.

Because we're not interested in getting the entire content, it uses a HTTP HEAD request instead of GET. Lastly, it supports multiple sites on the same host by adding a Host header to the request.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working yet (a problem with authenticating to our web application from the console application, I think), but the principle seems sound.